# Using Google Cloud Vision API with a hand-filled form

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to analyze exam sheets with Google Cloud Vision API. Below is a test sheet that I'm using.

Cloud Vision recognizes the name and questions #11 and #12 very well, including handwriting. However, ***it completely ignores the questions #1 to #9***. No numbers, no letters, just nothing.

The output text is `"Name\nJohn\nDoe\n11\nI don\'t\nknow\nthe right\nanswer.\nfor me.\n12\nThis\nis\ntoo\ndifficult\n"`.

Any ideas how to force Cloud Vision to see questions #1 to #9?

The code is very simple:

```
def detect_document(path):
    """Detects document features in an image."""
    from google.cloud import vision
    import io
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()

    image = vision.types.Image(content=content)

    response = client.document_text_detection(image=image)

    print (response.full_text_annotation)

detect_document('resources/scan_letters.jpg')
```

[image: Exam sheet example]

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Vision will detect text in the image more easily if the photo is thresholded.

I use the code I wrote below and it solves my problem to a great extent.

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

def threshold():
    img = cv2.imread("menu.jpg") #path of unmodified image.

    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    #ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY) #You can change values for best result.

    cv2.imshow('Otsu', thresh1)

    cv2.imwrite("test.png",thresh1) #saving path of the modified version of the photograph.


    if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff == 27:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

threshold()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's a great idea but didn't help me with the example above.